# Class as parameter in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I need to know if it is possible to pass a Class as a parameter to a method in Smalltalk. For example,

```
Classname>>method: anObject
self anotherMethod: aClass with: anObject.


Classname>>anotherMethod: aClass with: anObject.
|instance|
instance:= aClass new: anObject aMessage. //supposing "new:" is the instance method of aClass.
instance aMethodFromTheClassRecieved.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have:

```
Classname>>anotherMethod: aClass
  ^ aClass new.
```

and you execute something like:

```
instance anotherMethod: OrderedCollection
```

Then you'll get an instance of OrderedCollection.

In Smalltalk classes are objects too, so if you do `OrderedCollection new` you actually sent `#new` message to `OrderedCollection class` object. So you can pass classes around just like the other objects.

P.S. The main idea of Smalltalk is that it's highly dynamic and live. You can try the thing you are asking about in just 2-5 minutes, and see if it works :)

Comment: You're right about the temp variable, I deleted it from my question to make it less confusing.

Comment: I guess the answer would be: 'Yes you can, since classes in Smalltalk are first-class objects'.

Comment: Please, take a look at my example again. I wonder if that would work.

Comment: @whitenoisedb what is `aMethodFromTheClassRecieved`? If `instance` object understands `aMethodFromTheClassRecieved` then it will execute it. If not - it will rise _Does not Understand_ error

Comment: @whitenoisedb Why don’t you just try it? Do have any reason to believe it would not work?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Classes are just objects.